# Find the index of the last occurence of fulfilled criteria in a matrix in r

Tags: r, arrays, find, match

I have an array (`x`) in R of size 30x11x10.

```
x=array(-2:20, c(30,11,10))
```

Each 'grid' or matrix represents a day of data for a month (30 days represented here). I want to find the index (`i,j,k`) of when the last occurrence of a number less than 2 occurs. Ideally, I would also like the value returned too. If this was in Matlab, I could just use `[i,j,k]=find(x(x<2))` but I don't see an exact equivalent for this in R.

I have looked at '`match`' as suggested in other posts here, but it seems to find elements when they are specified, but not when a criteria (`x<2`) is given?
I tried this:
`xxx<-match(x,x<2,0)` but it returns a long vector of integers that don't appear to show what I am looking for.
Then I tried:`xxx<-match(x,x[x<2],0)` which looks a bit more promising, but still isn't what I want (to be honest I'm not sure what the output is indexing).

I think I'm probably asking a foolish question here because if I want 3 indices and the value returned, then I should be assigning them to something preemptively right (which I'm not doing)? Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Did you check the package **pracma**? It has several convenient functions which resemble Matlab style. Here is the [CRAN link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html). The function you want to look for is `find()`.

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti Thanks. The function is `finds` in that package. It is closer to what I want, but not quite. It returns the linear indices of values less than 2 (which I can use to index the value itself) but it doesn't tell me what 'day' it happened on (i.e. the 'grid' or 'i' in my `i,j,k` case where the data is 30x11x10)